# In Chrome's Custom Search Engine, how do you make the correct website icons appear?

Tags: google-chrome

## **Custom Search Engines**

When I create custom search engines, they work, but the image is a broken image icon.

[image]

The amazon search engine has the logo because I didn't create it. The ones I created all have broken image icons as you can see. How can I fix the images so that they correspond to the correct websites logo?